# jQuery mmenu Windows Phone issue (IE Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, windows-phone-8, mmenu

I'm currently working on the mobile version of a website, and for the menu we use jQuery MMenu. It works well on every phones and tablets I tested, except Windows Phones...

The plugin is configured with "positioning extension", but same issue without the extension :

```
$('div#menu').mmenu({
    slidingSubmenus: false,
    offCanvas: {
        position  : "left",
        zposition : "front"
    }
});
```

So the menu is displayed over the page, I can scroll down if the menu is too big to be displayed completely on every devices, except on Windows Phone where the menu is cut when I scroll down.

The menu is cut... With a remote debugger, I found that the distance between top and the red line corresponds to the height of html element in DOM (highlighted on DOM inspection with webkit) But in CSS the height value is 100% (html + body elements). MMenu website advices to not set height on these elements, I also tried it but it has no effect...

Also found [this](https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/226). It seems to be the same problem, but no answers...

Has anyone already encountered such an issue or has advices on how to correct it  ? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, was just an other custom script which did not produce errors but was in conflict with mmenu...

Answer (score 0):

I"m currently having this issue.  What script was conflicting with the menu?

Comment: I used a very ugly script to dynamically change the viewport meta attribute for a very specific purpose, and IE mobile didn't like it. I suppose that the width and height of mmenu are calculated from the viewport width/height, so if you change it dynamically there is a problem with the rendering of mmenu... But for some reason, there was no problem in Chrome/FF